# Paperclip 4 vs Paperclip 5 multiple pdf processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, text-processing

User uploads a pdf. Then

1. pdf is converted to an image
2. pdf is data scraped using a processor and saved into a text file

in paperclip 4
has_attached_file would look like this
`has_attached_file :mls_pdf,  :styles => { :mls_pdf => { :format => 'txt', processors: [:mls_pdf_processor_05_2016],
     }, :small => ["200x200>", :png] }`

I've tried multiple ways of getting this to work in paperclip 5 but no matter which way I do it, the original gets saved, the text file gets saved, the smaller image doesn't get saved. I can do #1 and #2 separately but not in one go.

I get the following error:
`Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/hello20181202-7565-qh0st4txt'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/identify:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20181202-7565-b8144p.pdf[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>`

Here's my model

`Listing.rb`
    class Residential::Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Residential::GeneralHelper

```
attr_accessor :dummy

belongs_to :appraisal, class_name: "Residential::Appraisal"
has_one :tax, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tax, allow_destroy: true

attr_accessor :_destroy

has_attached_file :mls_pdf,  :styles => { :mls_pdf => { :format => 
'txt', processors: [:mls_pdf_processor_05_2016],
 }, :small => ["200x200>", :png] }

validates_attachment :mls_pdf, content_type: { content_type: 
"application/pdf" }
validates_attachment_file_name :mls_pdf, :matches => [/pdf\Z/]
```

How can I get both to happen in one go?